# Is smarty dangerous for my server?

Tags: php, security, smarty

I use smarty for my free weblog service templates and users can edit templates.
Is this dangerous for my server ?
can they run shell or etc ... by smarty codes?

Comment: You can run arbitrary PHP code with Smarty. So think twice who you give access to that power.

Comment: please give me an example

Comment: `{php}phpinfo();{/php}`

Comment: I blocked {php} , is there another way ?

Comment: There have been bypasses in the past. So which version do you use?

Comment: I think its dangerous with the default setup. Imagine a user could type something like `{'del /S *.*'|exec}`. If you want give the users the abillity to edit template files, I would recommend to set `allowed_modifiers, disabled_modifiers` and `php_modifiers`. You should consult this reference aswell http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/advanced.features.tpl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything depends what you allow user and what code you have. For example if you have some plugins, user can use them in their code and if plugin displays some data that shouldn't be revealed for all users, that could also be a huge problem.

Users can also put JavaScript into template files so you should also consider to remove JavaScript from generated output.

You should also update your Smarty to the newest one 3.1.18 - because some bugs were removed and probably some of them could be related to security. In 3.1 Smarty you cannot use PHP code using `{php}` code if you don't use SmartyBC in your code but of course it's better to remove {php} just in case